# How to customize look of DateTimePicker for react native expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datepicker, expo

Is it possible to customize the color of the text and the borderRadius? Here is what I have right now and can't figure out how to change the textColor to white and how to make the borderRadius 8px.

```
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";

<DateTimePicker
    value={new Date(startDateLocal)}
    style={{
        height: 28,
        width,
        marginRight: 4,
        backgroundColor: primaryMid,
    }}
    accentColor={secondary}
    dateFormat="day month year"
    onChange={(event, selectedDate) => {
        setStartDateLocal(selectedDate);
        setDateFilter((prev: any) => ({
            start: new Date(selectedDate || ""),
            end: prev.end,
        }));
    }}
/>
```

The way it sits now, I can't make the text any color other than black. I also can't change the borderRadius at all. If I have backgroundColor set to nothing then it automatically has some borderRadius but if I change the background color I can't change it. Please let me know what I can do if you have any experience with this library. [Here](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker) are the docs for a reference. Thanks.